# Do I need to check null and "" while comparing String in Java?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have to compare two `String`s:

```
public String checkComaprision(String str) {
    if (!("Hello".equals(str))) {
        System.out.println("String didn't match to hello");
    }

    if ("".equals(str) || null == str || (!str.equals("Hello"))) {
        System.out.println("String didn't match to hello");
    }
}
```

Here I have used two methods of string comparison insider string. I have read at many places where we compare string with `""` and with `null` before actual comparison. But I think the first case will work properly, and if so, then why should I check for `null` and blank?

Is there any case where the first comparison will fail? Which is the better approach?

Comment: Answer is: Nope

Comment: The _yoda notation_ is there to remove the `null` check.

Comment: If you would write str.equals("Hello"), then you have first to check that str is not null. But "Hello".equals(str) does not need previous checks.

Comment: http://ideone.com/wn0p7R - I would use this. Without extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way that `"Hello".equals(str))` would ever fail, a string literal simply can never be `null`. Same thing with `"".equals(str)`.

The method `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` automatically checks nulls first.

---

To answer your question, using `if ("Hello".equals(str))` is just fine, but if you ever want to replace the string literal `"Hello"` by a variable, you should use `Objects.equals(greeting, str)`.
Checking for an empty string is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I was going to suggest `StringUtils.equals(str1, str2)`, but I didn't know about `Objects.equals(str1, str2)`, thanks

Answer (score 2):

in your case the firs comparison will always work because we are sure that "hello" is never going to be null. Now if you want have a variable like this

> private String s

then you want to compare with another throug a function like yours, you now need to make sure that s is different to null

> s!=null

if not, you may have a NullPointerException